# Can't defer javascript and CSS together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have an html5 theme that supports IE8 by js however my pages can't pass Google pagespeed test. I need to defer javascript and CSS. My page has following header:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollgress.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-wide.css" />
</noscript>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
```

I tried following code for deferring however my page didn't display correctly. I don't know javascript well but I think browser renders only scripts, not css.

```
<!-- defer.js begins-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        (function(scripts) {
             var i = 0,
                 l = scripts.length;
            for (; i<l; ++i ){
                var element = document.createElement("script");
                element.src = scripts[i];
                document.body.appendChild(element);
            }
        })(['js/jquery.min.js','js/jquery.dropotron.min.js', 'js/jquery.scrollgress.min.js', 'js/skel.min.js', 'js/skel-layers.min.js', 'js/init.js']);
    }

    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
<!-- defer.js ends -->
</body>
```

Here are my files:
[image: javascript]
[image: css]
[image: ie]

How can I defer javascript and css?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting out the script tags from the header and just add them before the closing body tag or use the `defer` or `async` attributes on your script tag that are only used by the modern browsers. :)

Comment: Tell me if it passes the PageSpeed Test.

Comment: I'm installing virtual machine

Comment: IE8 does not support `async` and only has partial support for `defer`.  
http://caniuse.com/#search=async
http://caniuse.com/#search=defer

Comment: Why in the world are you even caring for ie8.

Comment: I'm guessing that there are still XP users

Comment: If you see the Gary's specified link, you would get to know that global usage of IE8 is less than 2%.

Answer (score 0):

hope this one helps for js file

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");

element.src = "js/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, dfalse);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```